# Putting as many usercontrols as lines in a text there are in a flowlayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so I have a flowlayoutpanel, and I have an UserControl with a label and a picturebox. 
I need the flowlayoutpanel to have as many copies of a UserControl I made with a label, and this label's text has to be the same of the lines in a text, so
if I have a text with this lines:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

The Flowlayoutpanel has to have 3 copies of the Usercontrol and have the first copie the first line, the second copy the second line and the third copy the third line.

Comment: Please read [Ask], the [FAQ] and take the [Tour].  There is no question here...

Comment: The whole text is a question, I don't know how to do it, and that's my question, how to do it.

Comment: There's a lot in that question.  The reason you don't know how to do it is because you haven't really put any thought into it or done any research. Obviously the first thing to do is to get the lines from the `TextBox`. That is a task in itself and not specifically related to the rest of the question. Have you made any effort to find out how to get the lines from a `TextBox`? It would appear not, and that's why your question is inappropriate for SO.  You need to break the problem down and then research each part separately. If you write code for one part that doesn't work, then we'll help.